# Passing two values from child page to parent page

Tags: javascript

I have this script on child page that should pass a variable and an image to the parent page.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function choose(newValue) {
     parent.document.getElementById(location.search.substring(1)).value = newValue;
}

jQuery(window).load(function(){
jQuery(".td-image-finiture").on("click", function(){
    var finitura = jQuery(this).children("img").attr("src");  
    parent.document.getElementById(location.search.substring(1)).src = finitura;
});
});

//]]>
</script>
```

On parent page I have this code:

```
<a class="cboxElement" href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('', array('_secure' => Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure())) . $_option->getDescription() ?>?options_<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>_text"><?php echo $this->__('Choose the color') ?></a>
<input id="options_<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>_text" />
<img id="options_<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>_img" src=""/>
```

At the moment I cannot pass bot values newValue and finitura, it's only one at a time, what should I change?

Comment: what exactly is a `child page` ?

Comment: an iframe popup in this case

Comment: But there are already good answeres and questions regarding passing data between iframe <-> parent window (if they are in the same origin)